# Finding no. of edges in a graph

Tags: matlab, graph-theory

[image]

I want to find how many edges are there in C1 and C2? I have stored their adjacency matrix like this :

```
    1   2   3   4   5
1   0   1   1   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   1
3   0   0   0   1   0
4   0   0   0   0   1
5   0   0   0   1   0
```

If I give an input in an array as `[1,3,4]` O/P should be : `2`

Comment: Can you please properly format your adjacency matrix.

Comment: Consult https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.adjacency.html

Comment: Thanks @Suever I have not used stack overflow before and I was unable to print the desired adjacency matrix. Can you please help me now?

Comment: Thanks @Sardar_Usame for this whole formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your array to select the appropriate rows and columns from your adjacency matrix and then count the number of non-zeros in the result by using `nnz`

```
nnz(A([1 3 4], [1 3 4]))
```